# How to automatically add taglib descriptor to jsp in Eclipse or IntelijIdea?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, intellij-idea

I want to search in `jsp` files and find the files that use taglibs but doesn't have taglib descriptor, for example:

**Test.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <spring:message code="general.saveSuccess" />
</body>
</html>
```

as you seen above, in the `Test.jsp` i used from `spring:message` tag, but does not have `<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>` in the head section of page.

Now, i want to find all of the pages in my project that have this problem and fix it automatically by IDE(Eclipse or anything else).

for example something like `Ctrl + Shift + O` shortkey in Eclipse that organize imports in `.java` files.

Comment: Developers should be able to decide what IDE they use. Do you use maven? I guess a maven-plug-in do the trick.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and project is a maven project. what is the plugin name that do this?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse WTP's JSP Editor doesn't offer to do this completely automatically, but it can provide content assist for the taglib directive and its attribute values based on what it finds. Proposals for the prefix are based on the URI value.

[image: Proposals for the URI value]

Comment: i do not want to open jsp files and then press `Ctrl + space` and then select the taglib directive. i want to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [maven-jspc plugin](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/jspc.html)

[This article](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200807.mbox/%3C18223951.post@talk.nabble.com%3E) let me think the plugin checks for taglibs too!